# ProGuard - unable to compile in release mode

Tags: java, android, proguard

One of my modules uses com.rey.material library. So I added to app level proguard config file:

`-keep class com.rey.material.** { *; }`

But my app does not compile with following proguard warnings:

> Warning: com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't
>   find referenced method 'void setPadding(int,int,int,int)' in program
>   class com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'void setVisibility(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'void setVisibility(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'void measure(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'void measure(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getMeasuredHeight()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getMeasuredHeight()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getMeasuredWidth()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'void layout(int,int,int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog$DatePickerLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'void layout(int,int,int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setDividerHeight(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setCacheColorHint(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setScrollBarStyle(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setClipToPadding(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setSelector(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setPadding(int,int,int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setOverScrollMode(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalAdapter: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalAdapter: can't find
>   referenced method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void requestLayout()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'android.widget.ListAdapter getAdapter()' in program
>   class com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getPaddingTop()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getPaddingBottom()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void onMeasure(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void onLayout(boolean,int,int,int,int)' in program
>   class com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getChildCount()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getMeasuredHeight()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.app.SimpleDialog$InternalListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setWillNotDraw(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setSelector(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setCacheColorHint(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setDivider(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setItemsCanFocus(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setFastScrollEnabled(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView$OnScrollListener)' in
>   program class com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setFadingEdgeLength(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   requestLayout()' in program class com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced
>   method 'void setFriction(float)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'int
>   getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   onMeasure(int,int)' in program class com.rey.material.widget.ListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced
>   method 'void setPadding(int,int,int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker: can't find referenced method
>   'boolean post(java.lang.Runnable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$1: can't find referenced method
>   'void setSelectionFromTop(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$1: can't find referenced method
>   'void requestLayout()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$MonthAdapter: can't find referenced
>   method 'int getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$MonthAdapter: can't find referenced
>   method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$ScrollStateRunnable: can't find
>   referenced method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$ScrollStateRunnable: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$ScrollStateRunnable: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getLastVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$ScrollStateRunnable: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getCount()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$ScrollStateRunnable: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getHeight()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker$ScrollStateRunnable: can't find
>   referenced method 'void smoothScrollBy(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.DatePicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void setSelection(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'int getChoiceMode()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void setItemChecked(int,boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void requestLayout()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'int getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'android.widget.ListAdapter getAdapter()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'java.lang.Object getSelectedItem()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'int getSelectedItemPosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'long getSelectedItemId()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'android.view.View getSelectedView()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'int lookForSelectablePosition(int,boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'boolean onKeyDown(int,android.view.KeyEvent)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'boolean requestFocusFromTouch()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'boolean onKeyUp(int,android.view.KeyEvent)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void setSelector(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in program
>   class com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find
>   referenced method 'void
>   setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)'
>   in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void setFocusable(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void
>   setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find referenced method
>   'void
>   setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView$OnScrollListener)' in
>   program class com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow: can't find
>   referenced method 'int
>   measureHeightOfChildrenCompat(int,int,int,int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$1: can't find referenced
>   method 'int getChildCount()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$1: can't find referenced
>   method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void setCacheColorHint(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'int pointToPosition(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'int getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'long getItemIdAtPosition(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'boolean
>   performItemClick(android.view.View,int,long)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void setPressed(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void drawableStateChanged()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void layoutChildren()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void setSelection(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'void
>   positionSelectorLikeTouchCompat(int,android.view.View,float,float)' in
>   program class com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView:
>   can't find referenced method 'void setSelectorEnabled(boolean)' in
>   program class com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView:
>   can't find referenced method 'void refreshDrawableState()' in program
>   class com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView:
>   can't find referenced method 'boolean
>   touchModeDrawsInPressedStateCompat()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'boolean isInTouchMode()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'boolean hasWindowFocus()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'boolean isFocused()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView: can't find
>   referenced method 'boolean hasFocus()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$ForwardingListener: can't find
>   referenced method 'boolean isShown()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$ResizePopupRunnable: can't
>   find referenced method 'int getCount()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$ResizePopupRunnable: can't
>   find referenced method 'int getChildCount()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView: can't find referenced method
>   'boolean isInEditMode()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView: can't find referenced method
>   'android.content.Context getContext()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.Spinner: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setChoiceMode(int)' in program class com.rey.material.widget.ListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.Spinner: can't find referenced method
>   'void setSelection(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.Spinner: can't find referenced method
>   'android.view.ViewTreeObserver getViewTreeObserver()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.Spinner$2: can't find referenced method
>   'android.view.ViewTreeObserver getViewTreeObserver()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setWillNotDraw(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setScrollBarStyle(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setSelector(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setDividerHeight(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setCacheColorHint(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   setClipToPadding(boolean)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   requestLayout()' in program class com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced
>   method 'boolean post(java.lang.Runnable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'int
>   getPaddingTop()' in program class com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced
>   method 'int getPaddingBottom()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   onMeasure(int,int)' in program class com.rey.material.widget.ListView
>   Warning: com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced
>   method 'android.os.Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker: can't find referenced method 'void
>   onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.ListView Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker$1: can't find referenced method
>   'void setSelectionFromTop(int,int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker$1: can't find referenced method
>   'void requestLayout()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker$YearAdapter: can't find referenced
>   method 'int getFirstVisiblePosition()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker$YearAdapter: can't find referenced
>   method 'android.view.View getChildAt(int)' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker Warning:
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker$YearAdapter: can't find referenced
>   method 'android.content.Context getContext()' in program class
>   com.rey.material.widget.YearPicker

So I also added:

`-dontwarn com.rey.material.**`

But app still does not compile:

> Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:   Class       =
>   [com/rey/material/widget/ListPopupWindow]   Method      =
>   [buildDropDown()I]   Exception   =
>   [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of
>   [android/view/View] (with 2 known super classes) and
>   [com/rey/material/widget/ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView] (with 2
>   known super classes)) Unexpected error while preverifying:   Class
>   = [com/rey/material/widget/ListPopupWindow]   Method      = [buildDropDown()I]   Exception   =
>   [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of
>   [android/view/View] (with 2 known super classes) and
>   [com/rey/material/widget/ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView] (with 2
>   known super classes))

Any ideas how to solve that? What rules are missing?

Comment: Have tried without adding `-keep class com.rey.material.** { *; }` ?

Comment: Without it I'm getting the same, it seems `-keep class com.rey.material.** { *; }` has no result

Comment: I did add this library to one of my proguard enable project and I did not get any issues though. I might be using higher version of proguard, what is your android studio and gradle version?

Comment: Weird, I updated library version and now no issues...

Comment: Good at least you solved the problem. When I added it i didn't get any issues, that's why I asked you to try by removing keep command in the first place. Anyway check your build log, you might see some suggestions. I can see some suggestions, but it won't break compiling.